# Typing Arabic IPA phoneme symbol

Tags: symbols, arabic, arabtex

I am trying to creating the following table.

[image]

Following is my progress. I having an issue in writing the IPA phoneme symbol. List of the phones are listed on [List of IPA Arabic Phonemes here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Arabic)

code:

```
        \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{arabtex}
        \usepackage{utf8}
        \usepackage{tipa}

        \begin{document}
            \setcode{utf8}
            \<مرحباً  > 
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{@{}llllll @{}}
                    \toprule
                    Isolated & Beginning &  Middle & End & Name & Phoneme \\
                    \midrule
                    \midrule
                    \<ا> &
                     \<ا> &
                     \<ا> &
                     \<ا> &
                      'alif &
                         \textipa{[ا]}
                    \\
                    \< ب > &
                                \< بـ > &
                                            \< ـبـ > &
                                                        \< ـب > &
                        baa' &
                        \textipa{ب}
                        \\

                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
            \end{table}
        \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Lastly, any recommendation for editor that suites Arabic and English writing better than texstudio, because texstudio automatically uses RTL for Arabic text which is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue using XeLaTeX.

My code:

```
    %!TEX TS-program = xelatex
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{xunicode}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    %\usepackage{xltxtra}
    \newfontfamily\afont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
    \newfontfamily\ipafont{DejaVu Sans}
    \usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}
    \begin{document}
      This is English Text with Arabic text \textarab{نَص عَرَبِيْ مَشْكُول}
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{@{}llllll @{}}
                \toprule
                Isolated & Beginning &  Middle & End & Name & Phoneme \\
                \midrule
                \midrule
                \afont{ا}   &\afont{ا}      &\afont{ا}      &\afont{ا}      &'alif      &{\ipafont aː} \\
                \afont{ ب } &\afont{ بـ }   &\afont{ ـبـ }  &\afont{ ـب }   &baa'       &{\ipafont b } \\       
                \afont{ ت } &\afont{ تـ }   &\afont{ ـتـ }  &\afont{ ـت }   &taa'       &{\ipafont  t } \\
                \afont{ ث } &\afont{ ثـ }   &\afont{ ـثـ }  &\afont{ ـث }   &thaa'      &{\ipafont  θ } \\
                \afont{ ج } &\afont{ جـ }   &\afont{ ـجـ }  &\afont{ ـج }   &gym            &{\ipafont  dʒ } \\

                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT:**
As suggested by @Alan Munn in the comment. I have changed the font to Doulos SIL. And also did not need DejaVu Sans as I used the default ArabXeTeX package font.

Edited Code:

```
  %!TEX TS-program = xelatex
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

    \usepackage{booktabs}
   %\usepackage{xunicode}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\ipafont{Doulos SIL}
    \usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}
    \begin{document}
      This is English Text with Arabic text \textarab{نَص عَرَبِيْ مَشْكُول}
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{@{}cccccc @{}}
                \toprule
                Isolated & Beginning &  Middle & End & Name & Phoneme \\
                \midrule
                \midrule
                \textarab{ا}   &\textarab{ا}      &\textarab{ا}      &\textarab{ا}      &'alif      &{\ipafont aː} \\
                \textarab{ ب } &\textarab{ بـ }   &\textarab{ ـبـ }  &\textarab{ ـب }   &baa'       &{\ipafont b } \\       
                \textarab{ ت } &\textarab{ تـ }   &\textarab{ ـتـ }  &\textarab{ ـت }   &taa'       &{\ipafont  t } \\
                \textarab{ ث } &\textarab{ ثـ }   &\textarab{ ـثـ }  &\textarab{ ـث }   &thaa'      &{\ipafont  θ } \\
                \textarab{ ج } &\textarab{ جـ }   &\textarab{ ـجـ }  &\textarab{ ـج }   &gym         &{\ipafont  dʒ } \\                

                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Edited Result:

[image]

Comment: Why use Dejavu Sans as the font? IPA symbols are supposed to be serifed, and your main text font is serifed.  I don't know what latin font Amiri is based on, but you should be able to match it.

Comment: I would suggest [Doulos SIL](https://software.sil.org/doulos/)  as a suitable replacement.